# ng-repeat and Mmenu submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, mmenu

I am building a menu from a JSON file that includes submenus. I am using a plugin called JQuery.mmenu. When I create the submenu using raw HTML it works fine like so: (run code to see)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    //determines redirects go via shortcuts, clicking on the management icon on the main page sends the routeProvider /MG which it then uses to pull the relevant HTML file
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        controller: 'projectController',
        templateUrl: './assets/html/home.html'
      })
      .when('/t1', {
        controller: 'projectController',
        templateUrl: './assets/html/temp1.html'
      })
      .when('/t2', {
        controller: 'projectController',
        templateUrl: './assets/html/temp2.html'
      })
      .when('/t3', {
        controller: 'projectController',
        templateUrl: './assets/html/temp3.html'
      })

    .otherwise({
      controller: 'projectController',
      templateUrl: './assets/html/home.html'
    })
  }
]);

app.controller('projectController', function projectController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $scope.projectInfo = [];
  $scope.menuInfo = [];
  $http.get('config/Config.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.projectInfo = response.data[0].config;
    $scope.menuInfo = response.data[1].menu;
  });

  // $scope.activeID = 'HM';
  // $scope.activePath = "Assets/images/allActive.png";

  // function getImgPath(item) {
  //     $scope.activePath = "Assets/images/" + item.path + "";
  //     console.log($scope.activePath);
  // }


  $scope.setImgPath = function(btnPath) {
    console.log(btnPath)
    $scope.activePath = "Assets/images/" + btnPath + "";
    console.log($scope.activePath);
  };
  $scope.contentCtrl = function(id) {
    $scope.activeID = id;
    console.log($scope.activeID);
    // $scope.activeItem = item;
    // getImgPath($scope.activeItem);


  };


});
```

```css
/* Helvetica Font */

@font-face {
  font-family: HelveticaNeue;
  src: local('0'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf') format('otf');
}
/* Global and Overrides */

body,
html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
body {
  background: #303030;
}
#header {
  background: #212121;
  height: 96px;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
#content {
  height: 100%;
}
#footer {
  background: #212121;
  height: 72px;
  box-shadow: 0 -1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 -1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.fa {
  color: #8ea5d0;
  font-size: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.fa:hover {
  color: #627EB0;
}
.fa:active {
  color: #415E95;
}
a:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
  color: #627EB0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.title {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 6.5%;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.info_btn {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF !important;
  background-color: #8ea5d0;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  right: 30px;
  top: 48px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 0 21.8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  line-height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  right: 1.6%;
}
.info_btn:hover {
  background-color: #627EB0;
}
.info_btn:active {
  background-color: #415E95;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.info_btn:hover,
.info_btn:visited,
.info_btn:link,
.info_btn:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
.menuBtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: #212121;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
}
/*  causes the color to change when you hover over a button of class myButton */

.menuBtn:hover {
  background-color: #333333;
  outline: none;
}
.menuBtn:active {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #222222;
  outline: none;
}
.revNum {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 12px;
}
.footer_info {
  bottom: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.6.1/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="assets/css/mobileStyle.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px)" href="assets/css/tabletStyle.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1025px)" href="assets/css/desktopStyle.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="thumb.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.6.1/js/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#menu").mmenu({
        "slidingSubmenus": false,
        "counters": true,
        offCanvas: {
          position: "left",
          zposition: "front"
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="projectController">
  <title>{{projectInfo.title}}</title>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <a href="#menu" class="menu-link push fa fa-navicon">click here</a>
      <a class="fa fa-home" ng-href="#/home"></a>
      <span class="title">{{projectInfo.title}}</span>
      <a href class="info_btn"><span>i</span></a>
      <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><span>About us</span>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/about/history">History</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/about/team">The team</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/about/address">Our address</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div ng-view id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="revNum">Revision: {{projectInfo.version}}</div>
      <div class="footer_info">{{projectInfo.footer}}</div>
      <img class="logo" ng-src="./assets/images/{{projectInfo.logo}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

which is exactly how I want it to look, but now when I try the exact same structure but with an ng-repeat to pull from my json file I get this:

```html
<nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="item in menuInfo"> <a class="menuBtn" ng-href="#/{{item.id}}" href ng-click="contentCtrl(item.id)">{{item.name}}</a >
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="menuBtn" href="/about/history">History</a></li>
                            <li><a class="menuBtn" href="/about/team">The team</a></li>
                            <li><a class="menuBtn" href="/about/address">Our address</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

produces this(same steps to get here):
[image]

and these menus cannot be collapsed. Now the only difference I can see is really the ng repeat and when I take it out everything seems to work fine. I am at a lose for why this would even happen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can u create a  plunker?

Comment: Sorry I tried making one earlier and ran into problems, I got the "correct" version working but I cannot get my ng-repeat version to work as I cannot figure out how to include my JSON file that it pulls from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely issue is that the initialization script is in `$(document).ready()` but that is fairly worthless in an angular page since angular builds most of the dom after that occurs.

You will need to create a directive to initalize the plugin. Also will need to listen for `$last` in ng-repeat within directive before initializing if the plugin relies on all items present

The basics for initializing a jQuery plugin in a directive are not hard to find in a web search. Can always ask questions here if you run into more trouble

Comment: I'll work on that as soon as I can, but just to make sure I understand, what your saying is that the ng-repeat is running before the plugin is loaded?

Comment: no...`$(document).ready()` runs before angular has had time to create the elements ...especially if templates need to load

Comment: another possibility is check if an angular module wrapper exists for it

Comment: Ok, could I test this by just adding a timeout to the function or would that not work anyway? I only ask because I have never used directives so it might take me a while just to put one together and I would like to know it will work :)

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!! I used a timeout function and it worked so now I should be good to build the directive right? it will accomplish the same thing?

Comment: would be best yes...hard to tell what precise timing would need to be. You could use `$timeout` also in aangular which will push to next digest